# .htaccess rewrite to redirect alias to root domain subdirectory with http/https

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, redirect

I have set up a redirect in htaccess to redirect an alias to a subdirectory : alias.example.com is redirecting to www.example.com/folder.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alias.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

SSL is set up and it works well for any url such as https://alias.example.com/page, which goes to https://www.example.com/page.

However, if the alias url is in http, it goes to an 404 error page: http://alias.example.com/page to http://www.example.com/404.

Am I missing something in the code?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the subdomain might not map to the folder where your .htaccess is located in the first place, when requested via HTTP? Maybe the subdomain was only set up “for” HTTPS in the first place, in a virtual host that covers HTTPS/port 443 only, but not for HTTP/:80 as well …?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community.I have provided the working example. If it solves your problem do let the other SO user knows by accepting it through clicking the right button near the answer. In case you are struggling with the solution,leave me a comment.

Comment: The alias is set to the domain name and the folder. The htaccess is at the root of the domain.

Comment: Btw Prestashop is configured in the folder, if it's relevant to know

Comment: @AnkitRastogi, what is your working example?

Comment: @AnkitRastogi, ok got it! I'm going to test it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the working code for the same.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alias.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

The demo/test for the htaccess rewrite rule is at [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=7336f0b3-0d9b-58e9-8a65-5a6382b12b99)

We have clubbed the **https** along with alias **rewrite** rule with an `OR` clause

After this rule

http://alias.example.com/page redirects to https://www.example.com/folder/page

Comment: I have put the code in the folder's htaccess and not at the root of the site and it works. Thanks!